# Add css class to HTML or BODY tag in Vue.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bulma, buefy

I'm using the CSS Framework [Bulma](https://bulma.io/), respectively their [Navbar](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#fixed-navbar) component. For this to work well I need to add a css class to the HTML or Body element:

`<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">`

How can I add a class using vue.js 2.0?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't add any class tag on `html` tag.

Second, you can and should add that class to `body` tag on your static index.html file that you probably find on your root folder or in your public folder.

Let me know if works :)

Comment: Thanks, I only looked into the App.vue  fileand totally forgot that this file existed! It works :)

Comment: It's common practice to add class on <HTML> when switching light/dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

body and html tag are inside the index.html file. You can add the class there only.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this programmatically rather than simply adding the class to your html markup in code, you can do this with JS from the `<script>` section of your component.

I would do it like this:

```js
document.documentElement.classList.add('has-navbar-fixed-top')
```

Here, `document.documentElement` returns the `<html>` element, and `.classList.add()` is used to add a class to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@click="$root.htmlclass = 1"
```

.....

```
  watch: {
    "htmlclass":{
      handler(v){  
        if ( v ) {
          $('body').addClass('noscroll')
        } else {
          $('body').removeClass('noscroll')
        }
      }
    },
```